Can Pandoc preserve column width and/or justification in tables?
I am using Pandoc to convert from Latex to Word (docx). The document contains many small tables, where column width (and to a lesser extent justification) is important. However, at least with Pandoc 3.5 defaults, column width/justification do not seem to be preserved in (at least) Word-format output. Is there a way in Pandoc to preserve them?
Here is an MWE to produce a table with one wide column on the LHS, and one narrow right-justified column on the RHS:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{0.8\textwidth}|>{\raggedleft}p{0.1\textwidth}|}
\hline 
TL & TR\tabularnewline
\hline 
BL & BR\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}

This renders nicely with pdflatex mwe.tex mwe.pdf. (NB the horizontal & vertical lines are present only to clarify the layout; I don't care about preserving lines in general.)
But Pandoc's Word-style version has two equal-width columns, from pandoc mwe.tex -o mwe.docx.
And as an experiment, so does my attempt at a "default" Pandoc-Markdown version: pandoc mwe.tex -o mwe.md gives
  TL   TR
  ---- ----
  BL   BR

ie no column details. However, I don't understand all the Pandoc-Markdown table options, so I don't know whether it's the Latex reader or the Word writer that's losing the information in my real use-case.
PS My first SO post; apologies if I've messed up the formatting.

you can use pandoc -t native to see whether the latex reader preserves that information.

Thank you, that was useful. AFAICS pandoc does not preserve column widths from Latex.
